# How can I do a 'double webhook' on an incoming SMS?

Tags: twilio

In Twilio there is an option to send a request to a webhook when receiving an SMS on one of our phone numbers.

I am trying to get it to fire 2 webhooks to 2 different endpoints.

Can I put two endpoints inside a single  verb? Or do I need to write a Twilio Function to fire 2 webhooks? This seems like it should be simple but I am getting lost in the Twilio documentation.

Initially I was going to write a TwiML bin to try and handle this with the  verb. However in the documentation it says that no verbs can execute after  which means the second one will not fire.

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

If you need two different services to be notified about the one incoming message then I would use either an application of your own or a Twilio Function to send the request on to both of them.

You could do this with a [Twilio Function](https://www.twilio.com/docs/runtime/functions) that looks a bit like this:

```
const got = require('got');

exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {
  let twiml = new Twilio.twiml.MessagingResponse();
  Promise.all([
    got.post(FIRST_URL, { body: JSON.stringify(event) }),
    got.post(SECOND_URL, { body: JSON.stringify(event) })
  ]).then(responses => callback(null, twiml));
};
```

You'll need to add `got` to your Function dependencies for this to work too. Also note that this responds with an empty TwiML response. Since you are passing these messages into Front, I assume you aren't performing automated responses. This also doesn't handle errors, but should get you started at least.

Let me know if this helps at all.

Comment: Thanks very much for the idea. I'm trying it today and it's working about half way. I modified your code a bit for my purposes. One endpoint is receiving the SMS perfectly fine, the other one (`FIRST_URL`) which goes to Front doesn't seem to have any SMS messages coming through to the inbox. I copied the Front endpoint that was automatically populated on the number by Front, so I figured this should work?

Comment: Just now I copied the endpoint back in to a normal Twilio 'Webhook - HTTP Post' and it goes through to Front with no problems.

Comment: My guess here (and it's a guess) is that Front is [validating that the incoming requests are from Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/security#validating-requests). Since we are only sending the body of the request and no signature header, then this is now failing. You could generate the signature and add it to the request headers using [the process described here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/security#validating-requests). But you might want to confirm that this is what Front is doing first.