# Creating A Twilio Function to trigger 2 webhook endpoints (Autopilot & FrontApp) For Incoming SMS

Tags: twilio

I want to create a Twilio Function that will trigger two webhook endpoints for AutoPilotHQ & FrontApp.

I've tried what's suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56905449/how-can-i-do-a-double-webhook-on-an-incoming-sms)
which suggest create the following function. I did make sure to include the dependencies as well.

```
const got = require('got');

exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {
  let twiml = new Twilio.twiml.MessagingResponse();
  Promise.all([
    got.post(FIRST_URL, { body: JSON.stringify(event) }),
    got.post(SECOND_URL, { body: JSON.stringify(event) })
  ]).then(responses => callback(null, twiml));
};
```

I'm getting the following error I get from twilio is:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection: HTTPError: Response code 500 (Internal Server Error)
at PromisableRequest.request.once (/var/task/node_modules/got/dist/source/as-promise/index.js:124:28)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

The URLs webhooks are specific to FrontApp & AutopilotHQ respectively.

Comment: What is returning that error? Can you provide the details of what you did?

Comment: I created a function in Twilio with the following:

const got = require('got');

exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {
  let twiml = new Twilio.twiml.MessagingResponse();
  Promise.all([
    got.post(FIRST_URL, { body: JSON.stringify(event) }),
    got.post(SECOND_URL, { body: JSON.stringify(event) })
  ]).then(responses => callback(null, twiml));
};
"

Comment: It looks like the error is coming from the far-end, either AutoPilotHQ or FrontApp, not sure which one. Their server is returning a 500 "Server Error". What format are they expecting you to send the data in? JSON? xxx-www-urlencoded?

Comment: Reached out to FrontApp and that stated _italic_When you send messages to this Front webhook URL, you will need to pass exactly the same request headers as when you received the request in order for Front to successfully accept it. 

I hope this helps get you started - please let me know if you have any questions as you work through this _italic_

I thought the above function would send the webhook including headers and body exactly how it recieved it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this below Twilio Function work?

Make sure you add querystring and axios as Twilio Function [dependencies](https://www.twilio.com/console/functions/configure).

[image]

```
const axios = require('axios');
const qs = require('querystring');

exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {

  let twiml = new Twilio.twiml.MessagingResponse();

  let { 
      ApiVersion,
      SmsSid,
      SmsStatus,
      SmsMessageSid,
      NumSegments,
      ToState,
      From,
      MessageSid,
      AccountSid,
      ToCity,
      FromCountry,
      ToZip,
      FromCity,
      To,
      FromZip,
      ToCountry,
      Body,
      NumMedia,
      FromState 
  } = event;

  let requestBody = {
      ApiVersion,
      SmsSid,
      SmsStatus,
      SmsMessageSid,
      NumSegments,
      ToState,
      From,
      MessageSid,
      AccountSid,
      ToCity,
      FromCountry,
      ToZip,
      FromCity,
      To,
      FromZip,
      ToCountry,
      Body,
      NumMedia,
      FromState 
  };

    let url1 = "https://example.com/1";
    let url2 = "https://example.com/2";

   const config = {
     headers: {
     'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
     }};

  Promise.all([
       axios.post(url1, qs.stringify(requestBody), config),
       axios.post(url2, qs.stringify(requestBody), config)
       ]).then(result => {
           callback(null, twiml);
       }).catch(err => {
           console.log(err);
           callback(err);
       });
};
```

Comment: Thanks Alan that does indeed work for both platforms however it is trigging an ""Invalid Content-Type: application/json supplied":" error even though is succeeds. 

I tried changing the headers config to "application/json" which causes everything to not work again.

Comment: Hmm, I will look at it later, I wonder if the issue is the far-end sending back JSON and the Function above is not expecting it. Twilio does send `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` so the outbound is right, I just think the return from the servers we send to needs to be tweaked.

Comment: I made a change to the code, to return TwiML instead of JSON. Let me know if that fixes the issue. I think you were referring to the error in the Twilio Debugger.

Comment: That solution worked perfectly now. Thank you for teaching me something new. The only thing I ended up doing was adding some MMS handling for the mediaUrl & MediaContentType.