# Twilio - Inbound SMS webhook request to 2 endpoints/webhooks?

Tags: twilio

I'm wondering if some twilio expert can chime in.

I need to route inbound messages on one of my twilio numbers to two endpoints. The number configuration only allows for a primary and backup webhook/endpoint.

Is it possible to route to a twilio function, and have the function call both webhooks passing along the payload?

```
 exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {
 var got = require('got');
 var requestPayload = event;

 got.post('http://endpoint1', 
  { body: JSON.stringify(requestPayload), 
    headers: { 
      'accept': 'application/json' 
  }, 
  json: true
}).then(function(response) {
  console.log(response.body)
}).catch(function(error) {
  callback(error)
});

 got.post('http://endpoint2', 
  { body: JSON.stringify(requestPayload), 
    headers: { 
      'accept': 'application/json' 
  }, 
  json: true
 }).then(function(response) {
   console.log(response.body)
 }).catch(function(error) {
   callback(error)
 });

callback(null, "OK");
}
```

- Easier/better way to do this?
- Is the entire data payload what twilio normally passes to webhook? (All i see in inspector is twilMLFetch to the SMS endpoint

Comment: Yes, there is I answered this is another post, here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61617884/creating-a-twilio-function-to-trigger-2-webhook-endpoints-autopilot-frontapp?noredirect=1#comment109039655_61617884.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!