# Ask Twilio to pass custom headers in webhooks

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-click-to-call, twilio-programmable-voice

I'm using Twilio REST Api to create a call programmatically, with call-status and recordings web-hooks wired in. The web-hook POST requests are currently hitting the server but failing on me because there is a requirement for a custom header entry.

I want to be able to pass my custom headers (that needs to be sent in the upcoming web-hook request headers) when I create those calls with the web-hook urls. The custom header should have `dynamic` value.

I have something like this:

```
call = @client.calls.create(
          to: "+1XYZ",
          from: ENV['TWILIO_ACCESS_NUMBER'],
          twiml: '<Response><Record /></Response>', 
          status_callback: @@callStatusHandler,
          status_callback_event: ['answered', 'completed'],
        )
```

When I create such calls, I will have access to `sessionid` with a dynamic value, say `my-session-value`. Now when the webhook request comes in, I want `sessionid = my-session-value` in the header.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to add your own custom headers, you can try to proxy your requests through some other logic before it hits your application servers. This was a past in the post around forking webhooks you can look at and see it it can be modified to meet your needs.

[Creating A Twilio Function to trigger 2 webhook endpoints (Autopilot & FrontApp) For Incoming SMS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61617884/creating-a-twilio-function-to-trigger-2-webhook-endpoints-autopilot-frontapp/61645876#61645876)

There is an example of passing a custom `Axios` HTTP header below:

[Make a Write Request to an External API using urlencoded data](https://www.twilio.com/docs/runtime/quickstart/serverless-functions-make-a-write-request-to-an-external-api-urlencoded)

Comment: The header value will have a dynamic value. This dynamic value will be available when the call is created using (@client.calls.create), and I want those value to be available when it sends in the webhook request. The ones you had had static value passed around.

Comment: Your other option is URL query parameters, How to Share Information Between Your Applications - https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/how-share-information-between-your-applications